# Elasticsearch: Retrieving filtered and unfiltered count in one request

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I am using the following mapping in one of my ElasticSearch indices:

```
"mappings": {
    "my-mapping": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "groupId": {
                "type" : "keyword"
            }
            "title": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I now want to count elements matching to a search string which may be present inside of "title", grouped by my groupId. I can achieve that using aggregations and buckets:

```
/indexname/_search
{
    "query" : { 
        "term" : { 
            "title" : "sky" 
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "filtered_buckets": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "groupId"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, I want to know the count of all elements *not* respecting the filter. I could simply achieve that using a non-queried search:

```
/indexname/_search
{
    "aggs": {
        "filtered_buckets": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "groupId"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Current problem is: Is there any possibility to generate aggregation data containing the filtered count and the unfiltered count of only those groups which had a hit before - in one request?
For example:

```
"buckets": [
    {
        "key": "257786",
        "doc_count": 3024,
        "filtered_doc_count" : 202
    },
    {
        "key": "254640",
        "doc_count": 3010
        "filtered_doc_count" : 1
    },
    {
        "key": "252256",
        "doc_count": 2367
        "filtered_doc_count" : 5
    },
    ...
]
```

One way I see is splitting the requests in two while first requesting all filtered buckets (their IDs) and then requesting the counts of these specific buckets using `"terms" : { "id" : ["4", "65", "404"] }`. This is not very nice and I don't want to request twice (_msearch does not help here).

Second bad solution would be to persist the all-counts somewhere in all of my entities.

Is there any way to achieve what I described in a single request?

PS: Please correct me, if the question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Based on these:

> [How to filter terms aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251332/how-to-filter-terms-aggregation)
>   http://nocf-www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html

I made this:

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "my-mapping": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "groupId": {
                "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "title": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}

PUT test/type1/1
{
  "id":1,
  "groupId": 1,
  "title": "asd"
}
PUT test/type1/2
{
  "id":2,
  "groupId": 1,
  "title": "sky"
}
PUT test/type1/3
{
  "id":3,
  "groupId": 2,
  "title": "sky"
}
PUT test/type1/4
{
  "id":4,
  "groupId": 2,
  "title": "sky"
}
PUT test/type1/5
{
  "id":5,
  "groupId": 2,
  "title": "sky"
}
POST test/type1/_search
{
  "aggs": {
      "categories-filtered": {            
        "filter": {"term": {"title": "sky"}},
        "aggs": {
          "names": {
            "terms": {"field": "groupId"}
          }
        }
      },
      "categories": {
            "terms": {"field": "groupId"}
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There are several problems regarding this solution: I do not want to build buckets for all of the "groups" that exist. This can be hundreds of thousands and those can also not be paginated. So aggregating all of them without filtering is not an option. My question maybe is a bit unclear here, for that the larger count is unfiltered but only calculated for the relevant buckets.

Comment: so you need those buckets that have hits in them for the term filter but without filtering the rest of the records?

Comment: No, I explicitely need the size of the buckets which had hits with the term filter. See my idea of "filtered_doc_count" and "doc_count". I know, it's a bit tricky.

Comment: Sry, I missed that. My problem with getting the full count of specific buckets needs some information on the bucket (in this case the groupId). My previous question aimed to target this problem, and I'm not sure that you can do this in one query. Even if you had the first, filtered bucket set, the only way I could do the second query would be giving all the groupIds in the query, which is still ugly and slow.